# Hiding plugin on WordPress for smaller screen resolution

Tags: css, facebook, wordpress

So I have been working on this for a few days and my brain is starting to die out. I did have another problem with the same website but that's sorted now thanks to some great help on here, so here goes.

The other day I was trying to create a sliding Facebook Social Slider for WordPress, but after a big headache I found one that I could modify slightly to suit my needs. The plugin in question is the "Facebook Likebox Slider by ARScode".

This works great on pc, but on mobiles its real nasty. Rather than going into detail about the problems I have with it on smaller resolutions, I would rather just completely hide it whenever the page is less that 960px wide. I would imagine this would be in the CSS of the plugin but I'm not entirely sure. What are your thoughts/recommendations? Is there another plugin that will do the same thing but hide itself on lower resolutions?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your best bet to hide the plugin would be to use a media query. Do you have an example of the markup generated by the plugin?

Comment: After viewing the plugin demos, what version do you use? (ref. http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-likebox-slider-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/1021632)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you buddy, have been working on another issue I've been having. The media query below works great, I think someone should submit it to the author because that plugin is great to have but causes problems on lower resolution.

In all, thanks for your help. Loving StackOverflow it's the only place I've ever asked for help where people actually pay attention to what your asking and give you a good 'usable' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i've messed with the link @88 MPG posted and found this class in common on those sliders.
I didn't test on all of them (28 examples o.O), but my guess is that this will work for you.

```
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
    .fblbForm {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was going to be my approach, nice answer.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that (not discrediting your answer of course). Great help! Clear answer! Thanks :)